# Преобразовать строку в десятичное число с плавающей точкой

Tags: javascript

Нужно "3,611" преобразовать в число.
Чтобы    3,611 * количество товара = результат

То есть 3,611*2 = 7,222

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let a = parseFloat('3,611'.replace(',', '.'));
console.log(typeof a);
console.log(a * 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Обычно так делают:

```
var num = parseFloat(txt)
```